# Cannot parse expression of type DateTime

Tags: python, database, clickhouse

**Please, correct me in comments if my question is wrong**

I am trying to insert test data into clickhouse. For the test purpose I use datetime.now (100% correct datetime)

In the last line of my code I have an error:

```
clickhouse_driver.errors.ServerException: Code: 62.
DB::Exception: Cannot parse expression of type DateTime here: 2021-11-01 00:19:12.933220, 2021-11-01 00:19:12.933237, 1,2,3,4,5, "TYPE_K", "BTCUSDT");
. Stack trace:
```

How can i fix it?

```
from clickhouse_driver import Client

import os
from datetime import datetime

client = Client.from_url(f'clickhouse://default:{os.getenv("CLICK_PASSWORD")}@localhost:9000/crypto_exchange')
print(client.execute('SHOW TABLES'))

# field names from binance API
client.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historical_data_binance
(
    dateTime DateTime,
    closeTime DateTime,
    open Float64,
    high Float64,
    low Float64,
    close Float64,
    volume Float64,
    kline_type String,
    ticker String
) ENGINE = Memory
''')

client.execute(f'''
INSERT INTO crypto_exchange.historical_data_binance (*) VALUES
({datetime.now()}, {datetime.now()}, 1,2,3,4,5, "TYPE_K", "BTCUSDT");
''')
```

Comment: Please, correct me if my question is wrong

Comment: Like in any other DBMS, those need to be quoted.

Comment: Thanks, I added quotes "{datetime.now()}", "{datetime.now()}", but received error -- Missing columns: '2021-11-01 00:55:28.455322' while processing query: '`2021-11-01 00:55:28.455322`'

Comment: @vladimir Thank you but for string ('{datetime.now()}', '{datetime.now()}', 1,2,3,4,5, 'TYPE_', 'BTCUSDT');
I have ---
DB::Exception: Cannot parse string '2021-11-01 01:21:48.160583' as DateTime: syntax error at position 19 (parsed just '2021-11-01 01:21:48'): while executing 'FUNCTION CAST(_dummy_0, 'DateTime') DateTime = CAST(_dummy_0, 'DateTime')'.

Comment: see https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#inserting-data

Comment: @vladimir thank you. Solved my proble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution

```
def prepare_table():
    client = clickhouse_driver.Client.from_url(f'clickhouse://default:{os.getenv("CLICK_PASSWORD")}@localhost:9000/crypto_exchange')
    
    # field names from binance API
    client.execute('''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historical_data_binance
(
    dateTime DateTime,
    closeTime Int64,
    open Float64,
    high Float64,
    low Float64,
    close Float64,
    volume Float64,
    kline_type String,
    ticker String
) ENGINE = Memory
''')
    return client



def insert_data(client, insert_data, db_name="crypto_exchange", table_name="historical_data_binance"):
    """
    insert_data = {
        "dateTime": dateTime, 
        "closeTime": closeTime, 
        "open": open,
        "high": hign,
        "low": low,
        "close": close,
        "volume": volume,
        "kline_type": kline_type,
        "ticker": ticker
    }
    """
    columns = ', '.join(insert_data.keys())
    query = 'insert into {}.{} ({}) values'.format(db_name, table_name, columns)
    
    data = []
    data.append(insert_data)
    client.execute(query, data)
```